# An almost self-resonance phenomenon

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits, energy-conservation, oscillators

Consider the following oscillatory circuit, with zero/negligible resistance:

[image]

Let us employ a tiny demon who will be periodically switching between the inductors back and forth, so that exactly one of the two inductors is included into the circuit at each time moment. More specifically, at the "even" times $t_0=0,t_2,t_4,\dots$, the demon will be turning the left inductor on, switching to the right  inductor at the "odd" times $t_1,t_3,t_5,\dots$, where
\begin{equation}
 t_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n h_j,
\end{equation}
$h_j:=1$ if $j$ is even, and $h_j:=2$ if $j$ is odd.
Suppose also that the two inductivities are as follows:
$$L_1=\frac{16}{\pi^2 C},\quad L_2=\frac4{\pi^2 C},$$
in some system of units.

Let $Q(t)$ denote the electric charge on the capacitor at time $t$.
The change of $Q(t)$ in time will then be described by the ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$L\ddot Q+\frac QC=0, $$
where
$$L(t):=\begin{cases}
L_1&\text{ if $t_j\le t<t_{j+1}$ and $j$ is even}, \\
L_2&\text{ if $t_j\le t<t_{j+1}$ and $j$ is odd}.
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Suppose the initial conditions on $Q$ are $Q(0)=0$ and $\dot Q(0)=\pi/2$.
Then the solution of ODE (1) will be given by the formula
\begin{equation}
 Q(t):=
 \left\{
 \begin{aligned}
(-2)^k\sin\frac{\pi(t-t_{2k})}4&\text{ if }t_{2k}\le t\le t_{2k+1}, \\ 
(-2)^k\sin\frac{\pi(t_{2k+2}-t)}2&\text{ if }t_{2k+1}\le t\le t_{2k+2}. 
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
\end{equation}

We see that the amplitude of $Q(t)$ grows exponentially in time. In particular,
\begin{equation}
 |Q(t_{2k+1})|=|(-2)^k|\to\infty
\end{equation}
as $k\to\infty$.
Here is the plot $\{(t,Q(t))\colon0\le t\le t_{12}\}=\{(t,Q(t))\colon0\le t\le18\}$:

[image]

In view of the tininess of the demon, this was "achieved" (almost) without any external force and (almost) without expending energy!

> **Question:** Does this not contradict the energy conservation law?

(Confession: I am not a physicist, and this is likely a silly question -- my apologies in advance.)

It is well known that, when the frequency of an external force applied to an oscillator is the same as (or close to) the own, resonant frequency of the oscillator, resonance can occur, with the oscillation amplitudes increasing many/(infinitely many) times. But that kind of resonance is caused by the external force and thus requires work, that is, expending energy.

However, with our oscillatory circuit and the tiny demon employed, it appears that a kind of almost-**self-resonance** will occur.

Comment: Sorry, but the ODE you wrote down does not actually describe the situation at all; the currents through the two inductors are separate, and you can’t just instantly transfer the current from one to the other by flipping the switch. If you actually quickly flipped the switch as described here, what would actually happen is (1) the inductor that you flipped the switch from will create an electrical arc, or explode or do something else violent, and (2) the other inductor will have approximately no current in it.

Comment: Of course the phenomenon of self-resonance you describe is an interesting idea, but it doesn’t occur often in physics precisely because of energy conservation.

Comment: @knzhou : Thank you for your comments.